# Simple way to delete dataframe rows robust to instances where no rows match deletion criteria

Tags: r

One common task in data manipulation in R is subseting a dataframe by removing rows that match a certain criteria. However, the simple way to do this in R seems logically inconsistent and even dangerous to the unexperienced (like myself).

Lets say we have a data frame and we want to exclude rows that belong to the "G1" treatment:

```
Treatment=c("G1","G1","G1","G1","G1","G1","G2","G2","G2","G2","G2",
"G2","G3","G3","G3","G3","G3","G3")
Vals=c(runif(6),runif(6)+0.9,runif(6)-0.3)
data=data.frame(Treatment)
data=cbind(data, Vals)
```

As expected, the code below removes the dataframe rows that match the criteria of the first line

```
to_del=which(data$Treatment=="G1")
new_data=data[-to_del,]
new_data
```

However, contrary to expected, using this approach if the 'which' command does not find ANY matching row this code removes all rows instead of leaving them all alone

```
to_del=which(data$Treatment=="G4")
new_data=data[-to_del,]
new_data
```

The code above results in a data frame with no rows left, which makes no sense (i.e., since R found no rows that match my criteria for deletion, it deleted all rows). My work-around does the job but I would imagine there is a simpler way to do this without all of these conditional statements

```
###WORKAROUND
to_del=which(data$Treatment=="G4") #no G4 treatment in this particular data frame
if (length(to_del)>0){
  new_data=data[-to_del,]  
}else{
  new_data=data
}
new_data
```

Does anyone have a simple way to do this that works even when no rows match specified criteria?

Comment: +1: impressed by the ingenious work-around attempts.

Comment: Thanks for the simple and fast answers. Both approaches suggested by Joshua and Ricardo work well: 
new_data=data[data$Treatment!="G4",]
new_data=data[!data$Treatment=="G4",]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've stumbled on to a common issue with using `which`.  Use `!=` instead.

```
new_data <- data[data$Treatment!="G4",]
```

The problem is that `which` returns `integer(0)` if all the elements are `FALSE`.  This would still be an issue even if `which` returned `0` because subsetting by zero also returns `integer(0)`:

```
R> # subsetting by zero (positive or negative)
R> (1:3)[0]  # same as (1:3)[-0]
integer(0)
```

You will also run into issues if you subset by `NA`:

```
R> # subsetting by NA
R> (1:3)[NA]
[1] NA NA NA
```

Comment: So what if the `!=` returns an `NA`; any suggestions in that case?  (I ask because I've used `which` for that, and luckily have never run into the OP's issue, though now am worried I someday might...)

Comment: @Aaron: that will only be a problem if the result contains a single `NA`.  This will still work: `(1:3)[c(TRUE,NA,FALSE)] # [1]  1 NA`.

Comment: I guess I usually only want the ones that are `TRUE`, not `NA`.  Maybe I then just set the `NA`'s to `FALSE`?  `ok <- a!=b; ok[!is.na(ok)] <- FALSE`?

Answer (score 3):

Why not use `subset`?

```
subset(data,  ! rownames(data) %in% to_del )
```

(You were implicitly matching to rownames in the `data[-to_del, ]` examples, anyway.)
Of course once that works you can go back to using just "["

```
data[  ! rownames(data) %in% to_del , ]
```

Answer (score 3):

I like to use `data.table` for subsetting, since it is more intuitive, shorter, and runs quicker with large data sets.

```
library(data.table)
data.dt<-as.data.table(data)
setkey(data.dt, Treatment)

data.dt[!"G1",]
##     Treatment        Vals
##  1:        G2  0.90264622
##  2:        G2  1.47842130
##  3:        G2  1.52494735
##  4:        G2  1.46373958
##  5:        G2  1.12850658
##  6:        G2  1.46705561
##  7:        G3  0.58451869
##  8:        G3 -0.20231228
##  9:        G3  0.52519475
## 10:        G3  0.62956475
## 11:        G3 -0.06655426
## 12:        G3  0.56814703

data.dt[!"G4",]
##    Treatment        Vals
## 1         G1  0.93411692
## 2         G1  0.60153972
## 3         G1  0.28147464
## 4         G1  0.97264924
## 5         G1  0.50804831
## 6         G1  0.48273876
## 7         G2  0.90264622
## 8         G2  1.47842130
## 9         G2  1.52494735
## 10        G2  1.46373958
## 11        G2  1.12850658
## 12        G2  1.46705561
## 13        G3  0.58451869
## 14        G3 -0.20231228
## 15        G3  0.52519475
## 16        G3  0.62956475
## 17        G3 -0.06655426
## 18        G3  0.56814703
```

Note that if you subset on a column that has not been set as the key, then you need to use the column name in the subset (e.g. `data.dt[Vals<0,]`)

I think the creators of `data.table` may be working on a way to directly delete the rows from the original table, rather than having to copy all the non-deleted rows to a new table and then delete the original table.  This will be a great help when you're running into memory limits.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are not selecting which rows to *DELETE*  you are selecting which rows to *KEEP*.   And as you've found out, you can often interchange these concepts, but sometimes, there are issues.

Specifically, when you use `which` you are asking R "which elements of this vector are true".  However, when it finds none, it indicates this by returning `integer(0)`.

Integer(0) is not an actual number, and hence taking the negative of Integer(0) still gives Integer(0).

However, there is no need to use which, if you are going to simply use it to filter.

Instead, take the statement that you are passing to `which` and pass it directly as a filter to  `data[..]`.    Recall that you can use a logical vector as an index just as well as an integer vector.

Comment: What about when there are missing values in the logical vector?  I've used which in that case to prevent odd behvaior.

Comment: @Aaron, which is helpful in that situation.  But in reality, you just replacing one "odd" behavior with another.  If the goal is to avoid unexpected behavior, I would recommend handling it more explicitly, such as `x[is.na(x)] <- FALSE`