# Subsetting rows with logical comparisons when missing observations are present

Tags: r

I was attempting to subset rows from a data frame containing missing observations.  I can select rows that meet certain criteria.  However, I could not select rows that did not meet those same criteria when using `!`.  Eventually I was able to exclude rows that did not meet the desired criteria by using `-`.

Is there a way to exclude the desired rows with `!`?

Here is an example data set:

```
df = read.table(text = "
     state  county    var1.a  var2.a  var1.b  var2.b
        1       1       10       25      20      25
        1       2       20       15      20      15
        2       1       30       NA      40      25
        2       2       40       35      10      35
        3       1       20       45      10      NA
        3       2       20       55      20      55
        4       1       NA       65      NA      NA
        4       2       80       NA      30      NA
        5       1       NA       15      NA      15
        5       2       NA       15      NA      35
", na.strings = "NA", header = TRUE)

# 1. works, selects Rows 2, 6 and 9, rows in which columns 3 and 5 are the same and
# columns 4 and 6 are the same

df[ (which( ( ((df$var1.a == df$var1.b) | (is.na(df$var1.a) & is.na(df$var1.b))) & 
              ((df$var2.a == df$var2.b) | (is.na(df$var2.a) & is.na(df$var2.b))) ) , arr.ind=TRUE)),]

# 2. does not work when excluding Rows 2, 6 and 9, does not retain Row 7

df[ (which(!( ((df$var1.a == df$var1.b) | (is.na(df$var1.a) & is.na(df$var1.b))) & 
              ((df$var2.a == df$var2.b) | (is.na(df$var2.a) & is.na(df$var2.b))) ) , arr.ind=TRUE)),]

# 3. does not work, does not select any rows

df[!(which( ( ((df$var1.a == df$var1.b) | (is.na(df$var1.a) & is.na(df$var1.b))) & 
              ((df$var2.a == df$var2.b) | (is.na(df$var2.a) & is.na(df$var2.b))) ) , arr.ind=TRUE)),]

# 4. works, selects Rows 1,3,4,5,7,8,10

df[-(which( ( ((df$var1.a == df$var1.b) | (is.na(df$var1.a) & is.na(df$var1.b))) & 
              ((df$var2.a == df$var2.b) | (is.na(df$var2.a) & is.na(df$var2.b))) ) , arr.ind=TRUE)),]
```

The second `which` statement above does not select Row 7 because:

```
( ((df$var1.a == df$var1.b) | (is.na(df$var1.a) & is.na(df$var1.b))) & 
  ((df$var2.a == df$var2.b) | (is.na(df$var2.a) & is.na(df$var2.b))) )
```

returns:

```
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE    NA FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

So, I guess I understand why `!` does not work in that case; but I cannot figure out how to obtain:

```
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

How can I modify the second `which` statement to also return Row 7 in addition to Rows 1,3,4,5,8,10?  The second `which` statement does work if there are no missing observations.

The third `which` statement does not work even if there are no missing observations.  I know that `-` is used to remove rows or columns.  And I know that `!` is for logical comparisons.  I guess the third `which` statement does not meet the requirements of a logical comparison, but the second `which` statement does.

I suppose I can use the first `which` statement to select rows that meet the desired criteria and use the fourth `which` statement to select rows that do not meet the desired criteria.  However, I would like to know how to select rows that do not meet the desired criteria by using `!`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the situation where one is `NA` and the other is not; it should be `FALSE` then because it doesn't match, but you're getting an `NA`.  Since this is the only situation when you're getting an `NA`, we could just check for it afterwards.  Here's one way:

```
> ok1 <- ((df$var1.a == df$var1.b) | (is.na(df$var1.a) & is.na(df$var1.b)))
> ok2 <- ((df$var2.a == df$var2.b) | (is.na(df$var2.a) & is.na(df$var2.b)))
> ok.both <- ok1 & !is.na(ok1) & ok2 & !is.na(ok2)
> ok.both
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Also, it might be useful to make a new function to do this, something like this:

```
eqna <- function(a, b) {
  ok <- ((a == b) | (is.na(a) & is.na(b)))
  ok & !is.na(ok)
}
```

You'd use it this way:

```
> with(df, eqna(var1.a, var1.b) & eqna(var2.a, var2.b))
 [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: With credit to hadley's comment to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14903764/210673

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong here (writing from my phone) but it looks like the reason #2 is not working is just due to parenthesis.

The `!` is only negating the first half of your clause.  Try adding another set of parens right after the `!` and closing it right before the comma.

Also, keep in mind that `!` is simply inverting logical values.  ie it swaps T/F, meanwhile leaving NA as NA.