# Alternative to which() when no match is found in R

Tags: r, logical-operators

The `which` command removes all rows of data if no element was `TRUE`. Demonstrating with the `iris` dataset, let's try to remove rows for a non-existing species.

```
dim(iris[-which(iris$Species=="nonsense"),])
# [1] 0 5
```

All rows are deleted, but using the condition directly returns the expected result.

```
dim(iris[iris$Species!="nonsense",])
# [1] 150   5
```

This issue was addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903728/simple-way-to-delete-dataframe-rows-robust-to-instances-where-no-rows-match-dele), and the accepted answer suggested the `!=` solution above. However, I need to store the condition result in a variable.

```
x <- which(iris$Species=="nonsense")
```

Should I instead use a logical variable to prevent problems with `which`?

```
x <- iris$Species=="nonsense"
```

What is the best and safest practice?

Comment: Store the logical values or store the integer positions and do a check when subsetting `yoursubset <- if (length(x) > 0) iris[-x,] else iris`.

Comment: @Roland That is what I am using right now. It seems clunky though, and I have the tendency to forget the check. I was wondering if there was an elegant solution.

Comment: I would store the logical values. I would only use `which` here if memory was extremely tight.

Comment: @Roland Would you post your response as an answer to get the credit?