# how to manipulate (or index) a vector in R, using a boolean vector

Tags: r, vector, indexing

I'm trying to manipulate a vector such that it is indexed by some other boolean vector:

```
#vector 1:
V1<-c(1,1,1,1,2,3,6,7,8,9) 

#vector 2:
v2<-c(1,2,3,4,5) 

#condition for manipulation:
boolean_vector<-v2<=3

#indexing using the boolean vector, based on the condition:
v2[boolean_vector] 
[1] 1 2 3 
V1[boolean_vector] 
[1] 1 1 1 3 6 7
```

Here are my 3 questions:

1. How can I better write the manipulation on V2, such that I get the same result? (I believe there's a better way..?)
2. What exactly happens when I use this method to manipulate V1? I'm assuming according to the results, that R prints the elements that have the same index number according to the results of V2, and then recycles the same results such that elements that correspond to the index number of elements of V2 are printed. Is it correct? Why it is designed this way?
3. What is a good way to manipulate different vectors according to the same rules? If I just want to print all the elements that are less than or equal to 3, and then be able to use this rule on any vector?

Thank you,

Comment: Please ask a single question in a post..  Also where is `v` defined?

Comment: Thanks,
edited - it is V2 @akrun

Answer (score 3):

First of all, note that your vector will be recycled for the longer vector (questions #2)!

```
boolean_vector<-v2<=3
boolean_vector
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Evaluating the `V1` vector, the condition will apply the boolean_vector to `V1[1:5]` and then repeat the procedure for `V1[6:10]`. That is unlikely to be useful in general applications where rows might not strictly represent same sized blocks.

For a specific condition, use a boolean for the vector itself (question #3).

```
V1[V1 <= 3]
v2[v2 <= 3]
```

If the condition is complex, saving its result into a vector as you did is preferable (question #1). To generalise a complex condition, you might want to create a function that would return a boolean vector.

```
check <- function(x){
    res <- x <= 3
    return(res)
}

V1[check(V1)]
[1] 1 1 1 1 2 3
v2[check(v2)]
[1] 1 2 3
```

The solution stems from Roland's comments in my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37814729/5967807).

Comment: Thank you @nya , this is useful.
So in relation to your answer to question 1: 
you define a function and then run a vector through it in order to manipulate the vector?

Comment: @oba2311 Yes. That way you evaluate the specific vector for a condition that you need. It is the same thing that happens in code for question #3 answer, but it might not be useful if the condition is something complex.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use which()?

```
new_v<-V2[which(V2<=3)]
```

You may should read the Introduction of which() function.